How do chiral biaryl phosphine ligands enable enantioselective transformations across diverse substrates?
I'm working on understanding the role of chiral biaryl phosphine ligands in asymmetric catalysis, especially for reactions involving diverse functional groups like arylpyrrolidines, oxazolidinones, and other functionalized molecules. Specifically, I'm curious about:
How do these ligands control enantioselectivity across structurally different substrates... and also, what properties of biaryl phosphine ligands (e.g., BINAP, SegPhos) contribute to their versatility in such transformations?
Are there known examples where these ligands are used successfully for multiple types of transformations (e.g., C–N coupling, C–C coupling)?
What challenges arise when extending these methods to substrates with more complex or sensitive functional groups?
Any insights into the mechanistic aspects, literature examples, or catalytic conditions relevant to these questions would be greatly appreciated!
